# How can I source Terraform HCL variables in bash?

Tags: bash, terraform

I have Terraform variables defined like

```
variable "location" {
  type        = string
  default     = "eastus"
  description = "Desired Azure Region"
}

variable "resource_group" {
  type        = string
  default     = "my-rg"
  description = "Desired Azure Resource Group Name"
}
```

and potentially / partially overwritten in terraform.tfvars file

```
location                 = "westeurope"
```

and then defined variables as outputs e.g. a file `outputs.tf`:

```
output "resource_group" {
  value = var.resource_group
}

output "location" {
  value = var.location
}
```

---

How can I "source" the effective variable values in a bash script to work with these values?

Comment: You might consider using JSON instead of HCL to write your configurations. They'll be more verbose, but there are more tools to manipulate JSON.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use Terraform output values as JSON and then an utility like `jq` to convert and source as variables:

```
source <(terraform output --json | jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k|ascii_upcase)=\(.[$k] | .value)"')
```

> note that output is only available after executing `terraform plan`, `terraform apply` or even a `terraform refresh`

If **jq** is not available or not desired, **sed** can be used to convert Terraform HCL output into variables, even with upper case variable names:

```
source <(terraform output | sed -r 's/^([a-z_]+)\s+=\s+(.*)$/\U\1=\L\2/')
```

or using `-chdir` argument if Terraform templates / modules are in another folder:

```
source <(terraform -chdir=$TARGET_INFRA_FOLDER output | sed -r 's/^([a-z_]+)\s+=\s+(.*)$/\U\1=\L\2/')
```

Then these variables are available in **bash** script:

```
LOCATION="westeurope"
RESOURCE_GROUP="my-rg"
```

and can be addressed as `$LOCATION` and `$RESOURCE_GROUP`.